# Remove Item from Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've got an object that I get from a sql query and I want to delete an item inside of it. The thing is that after I delete it, that item has no information but it's still there as:

```
<1 empty item>
```

so I would like to know if there is a way to completely remove it and have a clean object with only my data."
The code is to establish matches between two players from the database and it used to work but I would have to verify that the selected player was not the one being left out since they are odd and I wanted a random one to be left out. So I realized it was way easier to simply remove the player that is not going to take part in the matches from the object.
I will leave the hole code.

```
    let tournamentID = args[0];
    let categoryID = args[1];
    let tournamentSQL = 'SELECT * FROM tournaments WHERE tournamentID = ?';
    let tournamentData = [tournamentID];
    let matchesCreated = 0;
    con.query(tournamentSQL, tournamentData, function(err, result){
        if(err) throw err;
        let playersSQL = "SELECT * FROM players WHERE tournamentID = ?";
        if(result.length == 0){
            return message.channel.send('Ingresaste un TournamentID incorrecto');
        };
        if (result[0].modality > 1){
            return message.channel.send('Este torneo es por equipos, usa .partidosequipos');
        };
        let actualRound = result[0].actualRound + 1;
        con.query(playersSQL, tournamentData, function(err, resultPlayers){
            if(resultPlayers.length == 0){
                return message.channel.send('Este torneo no tiene jugadores.');
            };
            if(err) throw err;
            let roundPlayers = resultPlayers.length - 1;
            if(resultPlayers.length % 2 != 0){
                let player = Math.round(Math.random() * roundPlayers);
                console.log(player);
                message.channel.send(`La cantidad de jugadores en el torneo es impar, el jugador ${resultPlayers[player]} no jugará en esta ronda y ya clasificó a la siguiente`);
                delete resultPlayers[player];
                matchCreating(roundPlayers, resultPlayers, result, categoryID, client, message, actualRound);
            } else{
                matchCreating(roundPlayers, resultPlayers, result, categoryID, client, message, actualRound);
            }
```

Hope I was able to explain my self.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please attach your code and data from sql query.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your answer.
Done.

Comment: Can you describe your question in more detail? Attach the part of query result and what you want really and what have you done so far for that.

Comment: What sql library are you using? And is `resultPlayers` an array?

Comment: Hey guys, I left my hole code there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `splice` to delete a particular index

```
var playersSQL = "SELECT * FROM players WHERE tournamentID = ?";
con.query(playersSQL, tournamentData, function(err, resultPlayers){
    if(resultPlayers.length % 2 != 0){
        let player = Math.round(Math.random() * roundPlayers);
        resultPlayers.splice(player, 1);
    }
}
```